# How to solve for square matrix $y$ given $x = A'yA$ for $A'A = I$

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

I am trying to find a solution to $x = A'yA$ for the square matrix $y\in \mathbb{R}^{M\times M}$, where $A\in \mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$ ,$A'A = I^{M\times M}$ is the identity matrix and $x\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ is a square matrix. Can you please help me? I am not sure if it is possible to find an exact solution. Is there a numerical solver I can use (in MATLAB) to solve for the matrix $y$ given I know $A$ and $x$? Thank you for your help and/or suggestions.

Comment: Just to confirm, $A'$ denotes the transpose of $A$?

Answer (score 1):

By inspection $Y = AXA^T$ is a solution since

$$
A^TYA = (A^TA)X(A^TA) = IXI = X.
$$

More generally, if $M > N$, then any matrix of the form $Y = AXA^T + Z$ is a solution, where $Z$ is an $M\times M$ matrix whose rows belong to the left nullspace of $A$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I needed the additional matrix $Z$ because the problem I am working on is $M$ = 10,000 > 100 = $N$. $BB^T$ does not perfectly recover the identity matrix, and $B$ is a non-smooth basis function.  What is $Z$ exactly, and where can I read more about its function/purpose?

Comment: What is $BB^T$? The matrix $Z = R\hat{U}^T$, where $R$ is any $M\times (M-N)$ matrix and $\hat{U}$ is the $M\times (M-N)$ matrix of left singular vectors of $A$ corresponding to zero singular values. The columns of $\hat{U}$ form a basis for the left nullspace of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

You can, starting with $x=A^{-1}yA$, left multiply by $A$ and right multiply by $A^{-1}$ to get
$$
y=AxA^{-1}
$$

MATLAB has a function to invert a matrix and another to multiply two matrices, so givin $A$ and $x$ that equation lets you determine $y$.

Comment: $A$ is not square.